# python scapy send function could not work

Tags: python, send, scapy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNUbX.png)

The error is different when I add "dst" argument, python.exe crash directly. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Please add your code and errors in text format instead of image

Comment: When I type "send(IP()/ICMP())" in cmd, it occurs "OSError: No error"; when I type "send(IP(dst="192.168.0.129")/ICMP())", python.exe crash  directly.

Answer (score 0):

please update your scapy version with the latest dev one !

Download it on https://github.com/secdev/scapy or [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip)

It will fix the issue